# Visual Studio performance test - unable to test report (SSRS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, load-testing

I'm trying to create a web performance test in Visual Studio 2010/2012 to test a report based on MS report manager.

The issue comes from a performance test framework - it doesn't execute java script. So, when I open a page with a report I get an error message saying that "This page might not function correctly because either your browser does not support scripts or active scripting is disabled". Because of than the POST request to a page doesn't work as well. Configuring security settings of the Internet Zones doesn't help either.

I profiled web requests with a Fiddler and created a test (Fiddler can export requests to a test) but it didn't work. None of the requests actually triggered report and database procedures were not executed (checked with a profiler). Something is still missing.

I'm wondering if anybody had the same task and faced the similar issue (I'm pretty sure that reports load testing is a common task, but google doesn't help much). Please share your advise/experience.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution. It's pretty simple and obvious, but took time to find it.
There is a blog post (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) explaining the idea. Hope it helps and saves time for you.